# Temperature sensor appears to be reading too high

Tags: temperature

I've recently bought an outdoor temperature sensor, specifically [this one off of eBay.](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/290840180099?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649)

I then went on to use [this tutorial](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/freshers/raspberrypi/tutorials/temperature/#step-two) to hook it up using a breadboard and such. The only difference being I used a 10kΩ resistor as I didn't have a 4.7kΩ resistor.

I first used it in my room and it read about 25°C, which was perhaps 1°C or so off the room temperature, however I then put it on the windowsill and it shot up to 36°C, which I don't think is plausible today in London!

What's going wrong, is it the wrong resistor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, nevermind, solved it myself - didn't account for UV radiation of the sun. Rookie error.